# Command not found using npm on a React project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, npm-scripts, npm-start

I recently copied used a custom script to copy my build to another project and that's where all hell broke loose.

When I try to run npm start I get this error message:

```
\node_modules\.bin/../node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

Things I've tried:
Deleting C:\Users{name}\AppData\Roaming\npm and the npm cache folder
I then downloaded npm globally

I also tried deleting my node_modules and package-lock.json and then running npm install.

I've looked into the Path for my files and they seem to be right. . . I'm all out of ideas.

I was also getting a 127 error code but now its just the  command not found one.

Here is a link to my repository
https://github.com/guivecchi12/storeFE/blob/main/package.json

I've also tried creating a brand new react-app and I'm still getting the same issues, I attached an image of my error message.

[Terminal - Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5mDf.png)

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall nodejs

Comment: Used your repo, did `npm i` and `npm start` and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I had downloaded Nodejs globally and also in my project, once I removed the dependency from the project things started to work.

Comment: Press the green check mark so the question is answered